# SQL Incorrect syntax near as Assigning output to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT id, @RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as 'number' 
FROM WaitList 
WHERE email = @Email
```

However I am getting error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

What I am trying to do is assign the ROW_NUMBER() to a variable.

I really need to get the row number from the WaitList table.

Could I put the results in variable table and then get the row number by selecting 'number'?

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: I dont even know what that is

Comment: RDBMS = Relational Database Management System. So which one are you using? The code looks like T-SQL so it might be Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Yes Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of the row that has the matching email address, but the table doesn't actually HAVE row numbers, then you should create a CTE to assign row numbers, and then select the specific row from that... something like this:

```
WITH NumberedRows AS (
    SELECT [id], [email], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as [Number] 
    FROM WaitList 
)
SELECT @RowNumber = Number
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE email = @Email
```

Note that if there are SELECT statements prior to this, you'll need to make sure you terminate the SELECT statement (or other SQL Statements) with a semi-colon.  OR, if you wish, you could just prefix the WITH with a semi-colon, like ";WITH..."

Comment: I get this error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Comment: The error message says exactly what it means.  Either execute JUST this statement as outlined, or put a GO before this statement if it can be in a batch by itself... or if it's part of a larger batch of SQL, then simply terminate the previous statement with a semi-colon.  For example, "DECLARE @RowNumber int; WITH NumberedRows AS (..."

Comment: I've updated the answer to be clear about the semi-colon issue.  "WITH" is a keyword used all over T-SQL on SQL Server, so it can be ambiguous at times.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  You cannot assign a variable *and* return a result set with the same query:

```
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as number
FROM WaitList 
WHERE email = @Email;
```

Assigning the value to a variable doesn't really make sense.  If you want, say, the total number of matching rows, then use aggregation functions:

```
select @cnt = count(*)
from waitlist
where email = @email;
```

Comment: I really need to get the actual row number of the item

Answer (score 0):

```
 select a.id , a.number 
 from
 (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as number
 FROM WaitList 
 WHERE email = @Email) a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id) as number
FROM WaitList 
WHERE email = @Email;
```